# Error con conexion postgresql y php ERROR SQLSTATE [08006] [7] no se pudo conectar al servidor:

Tags: php, postgresql

Tengo este problema, ya que tengo una pagina web subida a la web y como base de datos uso `postgresql`. Al momento de llenar un formulario en `php` y enviar a la base de datos, me manda este error:

> ERROR SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection
> refused Is the server running on host and accepting TCP/IP connections
> on port 5432?

Cabe recalcar que en local, la pagina web si me funciona y si inserta datos a la base de datos.

Mi archivo conexión es este:

```
self::$conexion = new PDO('pgsql:host='.NOMBRE_SERVIDOR.';port='.PUERTO.'; dbname='.BASE_DE_DATOS, NOMBRE_USUARIO, PASSWORD);
```

Comment: El mensaje de error te da dos pistas que debes explorar: 1. ¿El servidor está corriendo? Debes verificar si sí o no ... 2. ¿Está corriendo en el puerto 5432? Dependiendo de los accesos/privilegios que tengas podrás verificar ambas cosas de un modo un otro, por ejemplo, accediendo a PostgreSQL desde cPanel o desde la consola y ejecutando comando para verificar el puerto.

Comment: el servidor esta funcionando y corriendo en este puerto ,tengo otra aplicacion en ese puerto y ip crees que sea por eso?

Comment: ¿Otra aplicación corriendo en ese puerto? Es raro eso , ¿hablas del servidor remoto? ¿Es un hosting compartido, un VPS o qué es? Si hay otra cosa en ese puerto PostgreSql debe estar en otro puerto para funcionar y en la cadena de conexión debes indicar el puerto correcto. Intenta entrar a PostgreSql por otra vía (consola, pgAdmin u otra) para verificar que funciona y eventualmente saber en qué puerto está.

Comment: no si postgresql esta corriendo en ese puerto , funciona , me comentaron que a la pagina que estoy haciendo al servidor debia de instalarle algo al php para que vincule con postgresql pero la verdad no se